# Get average number of entries for each unique id within another unique id

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

I am using MS SQL, and I have a table like this:

```
dogid     incident_id     incident_flags
1         1               a
1         1               c
1         1               d
1         20              b
1         20              a
2         12              NA
2         14              a
2         14              b
```

I would like to find out the average number of incident_flags per incident_id for each dogid. So for instance, I would like this output to look like:

```
dogid     av_flags
1         2.5
2         1
```

These were found by:

For dogid 1, we have an incidentid with 3 flags, and an incidentid with 2 flags. Av(3, 2) = 2.5

For dogid 2, we have an incidentid with 0 flags (NA should be counted as 0, it will never occur with another incident_flag on the same incidentid), and an incident with 2 flags. Av(0, 2) = 1

Incident_id is unique to each dogid (you will never get, say, incident_id 1 under both dogid 1 and another dogid). Incident_flags will not be repeated for one incident (you can't have "a" twice under incident_id 1) but can be repeated for other incidents eg. can get incident_flag "a" for incident 1 and incident 20.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using aggregate functions:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/211809/1/0)

```
SELECT
    dogid,
    av_flags = SUM(CASE WHEN incident_flags <> 'NA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/ 
                (COUNT(DISTINCT incident_id) * 1.0) 
FROM tbl
GROUP BY dogid
```